# Session-user Counter not working

Tags: java, servlets

Good evening.
I am trying to add a function to my web-app that keeps track of how many users are using it. I tried implementing it but so far, no results. The printwriter keeps printing out "0", although it is supposed to be "1 user". I am new to Java and servlets. All help is appreciated.

Here is my SessionCounter class:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionListener {

private int users = 0;

public int getTotalUsers() {
    return (users);
}

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent s) {

    if (users <= 0) {
        users++;
      System.out.println("Session created");
    }

  }

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent s) {

    if (users > 0) {
        users--;
        System.out.println("Session destroyed.");
    }

    }
  }
```

Here is the code in my servlet which is supposed to show the user-data on the browser:

```
public class ServletProjekt extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    int requests = 0; 

    String firstName = request.getParameter("förnamn");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("efternamn");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String howoften = request.getParameter("howoften");
    String newsabout = request.getParameter("news");
    String[] age = request.getParameterValues("age");

    requests++;
    request.getServletContext().log("Added a new request-log//.");

    // servern skapar objektet, inte vi. 
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("förnamn", firstName);
    session.setAttribute("efternamn", lastName);
    session.setAttribute("address", address);
    session.setAttribute("email", email);
    session.setAttribute("howoften", howoften);
    session.setAttribute("news", newsabout);
    session.setAttribute("age", age);

      session.invalidate();  //sessionDestroyed() is executed   


    Cookie firstname = new Cookie ("firstname", firstName);
    Cookie lastname = new Cookie ("lastname", lastName);
    Cookie Address = new Cookie ("Address", address);
    Cookie mail = new Cookie ("mail", email);
    Cookie HowOften = new Cookie ("HowOften?", howoften);
    Cookie news = new Cookie ("news", newsabout);

    firstname.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    lastname.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    Address.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    mail.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    HowOften.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);
    news.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24);

    response.addCookie(firstname);
    response.addCookie(lastname);
    response.addCookie(Address);
    response.addCookie(mail);
    response.addCookie(HowOften);
    response.addCookie(news );


    SessionCounterListener scl = new SessionCounterListener ();


        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
        printWriter.write("<html>");
        printWriter.write("<h1> THANK YOU FOR YOUR INFORMATION</h1>");
        printWriter.write("<body>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your name:</p>" + firstName);
        printWriter.write("<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your last name:</p>" +lastName + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your address:</p>" +address + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your choice of often:</p>" +howoften + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your choice of news:</p>" +newsabout + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Your email:</p>" +email + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("<p>Request number:</p>" +requests + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("Active users:" + scl.getTotalUsers() + "<br>");
        printWriter.write("");      



        for (String ages : age) {
            printWriter.write("<p>Hours:</p>" +ages + "<br>");
        }

        printWriter.write("<a href =\"GetAllCookies\">View All Cookies</a>");



        printWriter.write("</body>");
        printWriter.write("</html>");
        printWriter.close();

}

}
```

And here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app >
    <listener>
    <listener-class>SessionCounterListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
  </web-app>
```

Comment: Do you actually create a session in your servlet?

Comment: @Henry It was stupid of me not to show all my code. I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Can please someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I see below problems in both your `ServletProjekt` and `SessionCounterListener` class.

1.Change your `SessionCounterListener` class as below (**you are creating an object of this listener class,which will be created for each user request,hence each user will have it's own user property,so you will never get total user.**)Note i have changed both `user` variable and `getTotalUsers` method to `static`.

```
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;    
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

  public class SessionCounterListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    private static int users = 0;
    public static int getTotalUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent s) {
            users++;
            System.out.println("Session created");
    }
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent s) {
            users--;
            System.out.println("Session destroyed.");
    }
}
```

2.I don't understand purpose of maintaining session,because you are creating and destroying the session in same page.You have below lines in your `ServletProjekt` class,

```
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

So you have created session for user,and `sessionCreated()` is called so user is incremented to **1**.

After this line your are adding some attributes to session scope.

Then you have invalidated the session
    `session.invalidate();`

Now users will be `0` as `sessionDestroyed()` is called on `invalidate`().

Then you have used `SessionCounterListener` class,to print the active user,which will be **0** for this case.

```
printWriter.write("Active users:" + scl.getTotalUsers() + "<br>");
```

After the step 1 changes you do need to create the `SessionCounterListener` class object,so you can just calculate the total user by calling `getTotalUsers()` on it.

```
SessionCounterListener.getTotalUsers();
```